# Sleuth/zipkin with ControllerAdvice is not working

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, exceptionhandler

I found there is an old issue [Sleuth/Zipkin tracing with @ControllerAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790619/sleuth-zipkin-tracing-with-controlleradvice?noredirect=1#comment74630500_43790619), but I meet the same problem with the latest version(spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.1.0.RELEASE), I debug it and find that the error is null, so zipkin just guess with statuscode. I have to throw the exception again to make zipkin notify the exception

[error is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZNKW.png)

[zipkin result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYv1V.png)

[ControllerAdvice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJG7l.png)

[throw the exception again, it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9GIO.png)

Comment: Can you create a sample that replicates the problem and upload it to github?

Comment: see https://github.com/fantasyofjay/zipkindemo1, ExceptionHanders, if return string, zipkin just log error as "500

Comment: hi, Marcin, can you see the demo？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes perfect sense that it's `null`. That's because YOU control the way what happens with the caught exception. In your case, nothing, cause you swallow that exception.

If you want to do sth better, just add the error tag manually via the `SpanCustomizer`. That way you'll add the exception to the given span. It will then automatically get closed and reported to Zipkin (you can do sth else than `ex.toString()` of course.

```
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionHanders {

    private final SpanCustomizer customizer;

    public ExceptionHanders(SpanCustomizer customizer) {
        this.customizer = customizer;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handleRuntimeException(Exception ex) throws Exception {
        this.customizer.tag("error", ex.toString());
        return "testabcd";
    }
}
```

Comment: it don't work, ExceptionHanders execute before HttpParser.error, and HttpParser.error  function will tag error with maybeErrorStatus again.

Comment: HttpParser.error:   if (error != null) {
      errorParser().error(error, customizer);
    } else if (httpStatus != null) {
      String maybeErrorStatus = maybeStatusAsString(httpStatus, 399);
      if (maybeErrorStatus != null) customizer.tag("error", maybeErrorStatus);
    }

Comment: I use another tag errorDetails, tks.  this.customizer.tag("errorDetail", ex.toString());